# Is it possible to alias an attribute through a belongs_to or has_one association in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to use alias_attribute or something similar to alias an attribute through an association. I can do something similar with `delegate`, but I have to delegate all of the generated methods (`attribute=`, `attribute?`, etc.).

Is something like this possible:

```
class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state

  alias_attribute :state_flag, :state.flag
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're stuck with `delegate` for this. The good news is you can delegate all the methods you need on a single line.

```
belongs_to :state

delegate :flag, :flag=, to: :state, prefix: true
```

You'll need to remember to save the associated state when you save the city if you're delegating `flag=`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest thing to do here is to use a method instead of an alias.

Something like:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state

  def state_flag
    state.flag
end
```

Then, you'll be able to call: `city.state_flag` to retrieve the state flag.

Comment: This works for retrieval but not assignment, and it doesn't add all the helper methods like `state_flag?`, `state_flag_changed`, etc.